# RegEx for Dutch ING bankstatement

Tags: regex

Is there anyone who can help me to get the marked pieces out of this file (see image below) with a regular expression? As you can see, it's difficult because the length is not always the same and the  part before my goal is sometimes broken down and sometimes not.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Text:

`:61:200106D48,66NDDTEREF//00060100142533
/TRCD/01028/
:86:/EREF/SLDD-0705870-5658387529//MARF/11514814-001//CSID/NL59ZZZ390
373820000//CNTP/NL96ABNA0123456789/ABCANL2A/XXXXXXX123///REMI/UST
D//N00814760/
:61:200106D1840,55NDDTEREF//00060100142534
/TRCD/01028/
:86:/EREF/SLDD-0705869-5658387528//MARF/11514814-001//CSID/NL59ZZZ390
373820000//CNTP/NL96ABNA0123456789/ABCANL2A/XXX123XXXX///REMI/UST
D//N00814759/
:61:200106C236,31NTRFEREF//00060100142535
/TRCD/00100/
:86:/EREF/05881000010520//CNTP/NL19INGB0123456789/ABCBNL2A/XX123XXXX//
/REMI/USTD//KLM REF 1000000022/`

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow ! could you add a text version of one of those string,it will really help us.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, Thanks for your reaction. I am pretty new here and this is not really my cup of tea ;-) I added the text.

Answer (score 0):

The length is not always the same but it does not really matter in your case. You can check for a particular pattern at the end of a string.

```
(?<=\/\/)([\u2022a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\/$)
```

this regex will look for a string of caracter containing bullet (`•`), numbers, letters (uppercase and lowercase), that followes two front slash (`//`) and is followed by a slash (`/`) and the end of the string ( `$` ).

You can test more cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/cZVt5R/3)